# possible to get rid of card in Rise of Tomb Raider

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

I am playing 'Rise of the Tombraider' on Xbox One.
I have opened a set of card.
Prior to this I had a skill that helped me focus on targets easily.
After accepting the cards this has become more difficult.
I there a way to get rid of (some of the cards) that I have 'won'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to sell most of the the cards (I believe there are some cards that can’t be sold). Cards can be sold through the main menu’s expedition tab.